# Are the same cities critical for vortex campaign victory for all races?

Tags: warhammer-ii-total-war

In the vortex campaign you need to gather certain amount of resources and perform 5 critical rites to achieve the victory.

I am playing as Lizardmen - most local capitals provide 1 Ancient Plaque per round, but few critical cities provide 10 of them, making them crucial to secure.

Of course, it seems that as much important as securing your path to victory is to deny your opponent the same, hence I am trying to capture/destroy as many enemy cities as I can. Once again, holding to the critical cities would be a wise tactical choice. Going north from the hot Lustria I've noticed only one or tho Dark Elf city with the Ancient Plaques symbol, yet they are almost as far (if not further - AI tends to keep accumulating resources and then perform few rites at once) in the victory progress.

So are the same cities critical to the same races? If not, how can you find which cities are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those sites are the same for each faction. Though keep in mind that Tomb Kings and Vampire Coast do not care about the race for the vortex.

The following locations are ritual sites:

- Vaul's Anvil (in Caledor)
- Mirror Pool of Tepok (in Forests of the Viper)
- Altar of the Horned Rat (in Headhunter's Jungle)
- Black Payramid of Nagash (in Land of the Dead)
- Shrine of Khaine (in Nagarythe)
- Vaul's Anvil (in Black Coast)[1]
- Ghrond (in The Chill Road)
- Tlaxtlan (in The Creeping Jungle)
- Chamber of Visions (in The Forbidden Jungle)
- Caverns of Sotek (in The Jungles of the Gods)
- Golden Tower (in The Red Rivers)

However, that they are "critical" is disputable. The way the vortex camapign was made, you can stop an AI from winning the race forever, by winning a relatively easy final battle, when they finish the last ritual. The actual pressure on you to keep up in the race is very low because of that (and why I personally think the Eye of the Vortex is a terrible campaign).

---

[1]: Yes, there are two settlements called Vaul's Anvil, in fact every elf race has one of those